# Installing Windows 10 on a Ubuntu running laptop

Tags: 14.04, windows

I've got a Dell Inspiron 3558 and it's running Ubuntu 14.04. I want to install Windows 10 on it. I have never installed any OS, so that would be a first for me.

I couldn't really find any videos or I don't know how to search for it. I have another PC which Windows, so I could make a bootable USB from it. I don't want to have dual-boot.

Comment: The question is not related to Ubuntu at all. You can install Windows as if there is no OS.

Comment: Oh, so it's just the matter of making a bootable flash drive and installing windows on it? Don't I have to do something with the drive partitions? As I said I'm pretty new on this.

Comment: Exactly. The installer will make partitions, etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Your 14.04 is well past EoL - end of life. You need to install 18.04 or 20.04 as 16.04 will soon reach EoL. Makes big difference if UEFI install or BIOS install. Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives and only in BIOS boot mode to MBR partitioned drives. In BIOS mode it must install to a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag.

Comment: Oh, right now I'm in the middle of installing windows... Haven't done anything that you said. I don't really know what many of the stuff you mentioned means. How should I do the things you say I should do?